# Allow some roles to update a column, and some others if it IS NULL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers, privileges, postgresql-9.2

I have a column `A` (type `int`) in a table for which data is not available at insert time of the other values. I do not want to split the table, as there is no other real reason to do so. I am implementing privilege separation at the database level.

Only certain users (who belong to category A) should be able to modify `column A` at any time. But other users (in category B, not necessarily mutually exclusive to category A) should be able to update the column if its value is not set already, ie. if it is `NULL`.
I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

How can I accomplish this? Triggers? Rules? Something else?

Comment: The case isn't entirely clear. `only certain users should be able to modify column A`? Should those user be able to modify the whole row or *just* Column A? Same question for "other users" ..

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. Please tell me if it is still unclear. Thanks. And sorry for the poor phrasing of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> only certain users should be able to modify column A
> ...
> other users should be able to update the column if  ... it is NULL.

Revoke `UPDATE` (and `DELETE` ?!?) from `public` and everybody else who should not have the privilege.

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE tbl FROM public;
REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE tbl FROM ...
```

Create a (group-)role `some_users` that is allowed to update `col_a` (and nothing else):

```
CREATE ROLE some_users;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE (col_a) ON TABLE tbl TO some_users;
```

Why the `SELECT`? [The manual on `GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html):

> In practice, any nontrivial `UPDATE` command will require `SELECT`
> privilege as well, since it must reference table columns to determine
> which rows to update, and/or to compute new values for columns.

This way, you have a *single point* where you dole out privileges for the column.
Create another (group-)role `certain_users` that can do everything `some_users` can (plus some more):

```
CREATE ROLE certain_users;
GRANT some_users TO certain_users;
```

Grant membership in these roles to user-roles as needed:

```
GRANT some_users TO lowly_user;
GRANT certain_users TO chief_user;
```

Create a conditional trigger, similar to what [@Daniel provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15921276/939860), but with another condition using [`pg_has_role()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl_value_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.col_a IS NOT NULL AND NOT pg_has_role('some_users', 'member'))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE always_fail();
```

Using the trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION always_fail()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- To fail with exception, rolling back the whole transaction
   -- use this instead:
   -- RAISE EXCEPTION 'value is not null';
    
   -- Do nothing instead, letting the rest of the transaction commit.
   -- Requires BEFORE trigger.
   RAISE WARNING 'col_a IS NOT NULL. User % is too ambitious!', current_user;
   RETURN NULL;  -- effectively aborts UPDATE
END
$func$;
```

#### Now:

- The general public is restricted from updating the table completely.
- `some_users` and `certain_users` are allowed to update the column `col_a` (and nothing else),
- Only changes from `certain_users` go through once `col_a is NOT NULL`.

**Note** that **superusers** are member of any group automatically. So the form `NOT pg_has_role(...)` *enables* superusers, while an inverse logic would potentially prohibit superusers from updating the column.

Answer (score 4):

An update trigger should work. It would need to check the old value and abort the update if it is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
-- setup
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY, value int);

-- trigger function that always fails
CREATE FUNCTION always_fail() RETURNS trigger as $$ begin raise exception 'value is not null'; end; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- create the trigger
CREATE TRIGGER tbl_value_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl FOR EACH ROW WHEN (old.value is not null) EXECUTE PROCEDURE always_fail();

-- test it
INSERT INTO tbl(value) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl(value) VALUES (NULL);
UPDATE tbl SET value=2 WHERE tbl_id=1;
UPDATE tbl SET value=3 WHERE tbl_id=1; -- fails
UPDATE tbl SET value=2 WHERE tbl_id=2;
UPDATE tbl SET value=3 WHERE tbl_id=2; -- fails

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE tbl; 
DROP FUNCTION always_fail();
```

Notes:

- I have to create a trigger function (`CREATE FUNCTION`) because `CREATE TRIGGER` expects a trigger function and does not accept a normal function, so using `CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE PROCEDURE raise exception 'value not null'` is not possible
- The trigger is evaluated before each update, i.e.

  - INSERTS are not checked, so you can insert NULLs
  - the check happens before the update, so it can be aborted
- I have to use `FOR EACH ROW`, otherwise I'd be unable to check the `OLD.value`

Comment: While this goes some way, it fails to distinguish between "some users" and "other users". *Nobody* can update a row with `value is not null` any more, not even superusers.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that's correct; I managed to oversee that part of the question :-( In that case, `current_user` should somehow be integrated into the trigger or the function, depending on how the check should be done.

Comment: I provided another answer that should go the rest of the way. But +1 for what you already had. It's so much better than the one sloppy line of Daniel Hilgarth, that somehow managed to gather 3 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

To grant the unconditional update privilege to some users make they members of a role with that privilege.

```
create role the_role;
grant update on table t to the_role;
grant the_role to the_user;
```

Now this update query will only work if the current user is member of `the_role` or if the value is null:

```
update t
set A = 1
where
    id = 1
    and (
        A is null
        or
        pg_has_role('the_role', 'usage')
    )
```

[Access privileges functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE)

[Database Roles](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/user-manag.html)

Comment: why do say triggers are non-sense in this case? Your solution would work, but I would have to implement the checks everywhere I use the query. would it not be better to do it server-side? what is the problem with using triggers here though? i am curious

Comment: @richy I think I misunderstood you question. Edited.